# Translation and caching in PHP powered websites

Tags: php, smarty, multilingual

I have a very simple question to ask!

I wish to make a website that supports multi languages; 
- i intend to use smarty templates for caching purposes.
- i intent to use tables or csv files for multiple language strings storage.
- i would like to use google translate api to translate LIVE a string which could not be found in the language pack (incase).
- i know using google would make the page loading slow.

my question here is; keeping in mind the aforementioned scenario; would the smarty caching make it helpful to use google or table fetching translations to load pages faster??

furthermore, can u guide me a little bit how caching is done in smarty ??

thanks! any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Imho Smarty does no caching at all (well, it saves the compiled template, but that isn't what you would call caching.)

Comment: ohhh i see! than is there any way i can use the aforementioned concept? caching? :D

Comment: read this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630714/smarty-the-best-choice/630751#630751

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smarty does caching and is rather good at it: that's one of the reasons I use it. The [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/) is quite easy to follow (look at section 14). Caching the final output will surely speed up your pages; just check if a page is already cached before querying for translation.

Comment: ohh thats what i used to think regarding smarty! thanks a bunch :)